# Phonegap Application not showing JPG Files

Tags: ios, html, cordova

I
am writing an ios application using phonegap
am showing some images in my app
PNG images are working fine , but the JPG images not working at all , am having a question marks instead of the images

```
<div>
<img src="http://whatever.com/images/myimage.png" />
<img src="http://whatever.com/images/myimage.jpg" />
</div>
```

the first one is working fine but the other one is not
and am pretty sure that the spelling is correct , and no capital lower case issues

Comment: You should probably give an example of a broken file.

Comment: There is no reason that jpg won't work. Image URL must have been incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound odd but phonegap can be ultra picky. Try typing jpg uppercase: myimage.JPG
I have no idea why that would make any difference but it did for me!

Comment: Okay I need to clarify this. In Phonegap it allows you to add a filename without being case sensitive. The image shows up in the preview on the code screen and when you preview it in a browsers. BUT it will NOT show when you test it on the app unless the filename is an EXACT match including the case.

Comment: the same code showing data on android , i don't know what the hell is going on with ios